# Why JS object created by using Object.create does not allow to console.log value of its properties?

Tags: javascript

I am creating an object instance using `Object.create(student)`. It has two properties: `name` and `age`.

I can access `name` by using console.log object method getName(). However, when I am trying to get the name by using `console.log(instance.name)` it does not print anything.
Why is that?

```js
let student = {};

student.name = "";
student.age = undefined;
student.setUp = (name, age) => {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
};

student.show = () => {
  console.log(Object.entries(this));
};

student.getName = () => {
  console.log(this.name);
};

let instance = Object.create(student);
instance.setUp("Andy", 23);

instance.show();
// instance.getName()

console.log(instance.name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is actually something else than what you though. In your code, you accidently started to work with the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object that you thought it was your `student` instance.

The issue is caused by the use of [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to this, arguments or super, and should not be used as methods.

So the arrow function you're using are in your code are referencing the `window` object thus you don't get the result you expect.

The solution is quite easy, use the *[traditional functions syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)*. Here's a live demo illustrating your code after correction:

```js
let student = {};

student.name = "";

student.age = undefined;
/** arrow function is replaced with the traditional function syntax */
student.setUp = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
};

/** arrow function is replaced with the traditional function syntax */
student.show = function() {
  console.log(Object.entries(this));
};

/** arrow function is replaced with the traditional function syntax */
student.getName = function() {
  console.log(this.name);
};

let instance = Object.create(student);

instance.setUp("Andy", 23);

/** prints the object entries (keys, values) */
instance.show();

/** prints the name (Andy) */
instance.getName();

/** same, prints the name (Andy) */
console.log(instance.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as "methods" altering `this` instance, it does not work, because:

> Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to
> [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) or [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super),
> and should not be used as [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Method).

```
let student = {};

student.name = "";
student.age = undefined;
student.setUp = function (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
};

student.show = function () {
  console.log(Object.entries(this));
};

student.getName = function () {
  console.log(this.name);
};

let instance = Object.create(student);

instance.setUp("Andy", 23);

instance.show();
instance.getName()

console.log(instance.name);
```

Regular functions have `this` binding so it works for this purpose.

In our original code you are effectively setting properties to enclosing (global) scope. It would not be possible if you used the [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Comment: Your code is correct. Maybe explain why?

Comment: He changed the () => arrow function approach to function () {} approach, therefore this keyword inside it refers to the object itself, not to the window. In your previous code, this refered to window and not to your object.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this a better aproach? Also, it works...

```
function StudentModel(name, age) {
    let self = this;
    let _name = name;
    let _age = age;

    self.getName = () => _name;
    self.getAge = () => _age;
}

let instance = new StudentModel("Andy", 23);
console.log(instance.getName());
console.log(instance.getAge());
```

Btw, in your getName method you are using the `() =>` arrow function approach, inside that arrow function, `this` is assigned to `window`. That's why you are not able to `console.log` it out.

Comment: the question is not about finding *a better approach*...

Comment: Ok, you're right. I got carried away a litle. But, it still is one of the ways of solving this problem.